# Stop detached strongloop application

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I installed loopback on my server (ubuntu) and then created an app and use the command slc run to run... everything works as expected. 
Now i have 1 question and also 1 issue i am facing with:

**The question**: i need to use slc run command but to keep the app "alive" also after i close the terminal. For that i used the --detach option and it works, What i wanted to know if the --detach option is the best practice or i need to do it in a different way.

**The issue**: After i use the --detach i don't really know how to stop it. Is there a command that i can use to stop the process from running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To stop a `--detach`ed process, go to the same directory it was run from and do `slc runctl stop`. There are a number of `runctl` commands, but `stop` is probably the one you are most interested in.

Best practices is a longer answer. The short version is: don't use `--detach` *ever* and do use an init script to run your app and keep it running (probably Upstart, since you're on Ubuntu).

### Using `slc run`

If you wan to run `slc run` as an Upstart job you can install strong-service-install with `npm install -g strong-service-install`. This will give you `sl-svc-install`, a utility for creating Upstart and systemd services.

You'll end up running something like `sudo sl-svc-install --name my-app --user youruser --cwd /path/to/app/root -- slc run .` which should create a Upstart job named `my-app` which will run your app as your uid from the app's root. Your app's stdout/stderr will be sent to /var/log/upstart/my-app.log. If you are using a version of Ubuntu older than 12.04 you'll need to specify `--upstart 0.6` and your logs will end up going to syslog instead.

### Using `slc pm`

Another, possibly easier route, is to use `slc pm`, which operates at a level above `slc run` and happens to be easier to install as an OS service. For this route you already have everything installed. Run `sudo slc pm-install` and a `strong-pm` Upstart service will be installed as well as a `strong-pm` user to run it as with a $HOME of /var/lib/strong-pm.

Where the PM approach gets slightly more complicated is that you have to deploy your app to it. Most likely this is just a matter of going to your app root and running `slc deploy http://localhost:8701/`, but the specifics will depend on your app. You can configure environment variables for your app, deploy new versions, and your logs will show up in /var/log/upstart/strong-pm.log.

### General Best Practices

For either of the options above, I recommend *not* doing `npm install -g strongloop` on your server since it includes things like yeoman generators and other tools that are more useful on a workstation than a server.

If you want to go the `slc run` route, you would do `npm install -g strong-supervisor strong-service-install` and replace your `slc run` with `sl-run`.

If you want to go the `slc pm` route, you would do `npm install -g strong-pm` and replace `slc pm-install` with `sl-pm-install`.

#### Disclaimer

I work at StrongLoop and primarily work on these tools.

Comment: Wow man!! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I will try it and will let you know. Btw I really like what you guys did it is a great product !!

Comment: For those running Loopback's stock AWS AMI, I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/stracqan/0c85e27c2e7da1a38b92) based on my experience getting this up and running.  A few things differed from this answer, namely, I had to use `--port 8701` instead of `--listen 8701` on my `slc pm-install` command.  Great answer.

Comment: @AngeloS thanks for pointing that out. It's actually even easier than that, since port 8701 is the default, so you don't even need to use the option :-)

Answer (score 2):

View the status of running apps using:

```
slc ctl status
```

Example output:

```
Service ID: 1
Service Name: app
Environment variables:
  No environment variables defined
Instances:
    Version  Agent version  Debugger version  Cluster size  Driver metadata
     5.2.1       2.0.3             n/a              1             N/A
Processes:
       ID      PID  WID  Listening Ports  Tracking objects?  CPU profiling?  Tracing?  Debugging?
    1.1.2708  2708   0
    1.1.5836  5836   1     0.0.0.0:3001

Service ID: 2
Service Name: default
Environment variables:
  No environment variables defined
Instances:
    Version  Agent version  Debugger version  Cluster size  Driver metadata
     5.2.1       2.0.3             n/a              1             N/A
Processes:
       ID      PID  WID  Listening Ports  Tracking objects?  CPU profiling?  Tracing?  Debugging?
    2.1.2760  2760   0
    2.1.1676  1676   1     0.0.0.0:3002
```

To kill the first app, use `slc ctrl stop`

```
slc ctl stop app
Service "app" hard stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

What if i have to run the application as a cluster ? Can i still do it via the upstart created.
Like
sudo sl-svc-install --name my-app --user youruser --cwd /path/to/app/root -- slc run --cluster 4 .

I tried doing this but the /etc/init/my-app.conf does not show any information about the cluster.